# $(A\cup B)\cap C = A\cup(B\cap C)$ if and only if $A\subset C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried to prove this statement:

$$[(A\cup B)\cap C = A\cup(B\cap C)]\iff A\subset C$$

I did it in the following way, can anyone tell me if it's correct what I've done?

$\leftarrow$ Assume $A\subset C$, then $\forall x \in A$, $x\in C$

Then, $\forall x \in (A\cup B)\cap C$, $x\in C$ and $\in B$

Similarly, for $\forall x \in A\cup(B\cap C)$, $x\in B$ and $x\in C$

So $(A\cup B)\cap C = A\cup(B\cap C)$

$\rightarrow$ I didn't know how to do the counterpart.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Okay, understood Lord!

Comment: @SjoerdSmaal, after the hypothesis, your first statement is not true. "Then, $\forall x\in\ldots$". The correct is "... $x\in C$ and $x\in A$ or $x\in B$". Then, on each case you continue your argument accordingly.

Comment: For the counterpart, assume the LHS is true and then assume the RHS is false; that is, there exists some $x \in A$ that is not in $C$. Then reach a contradiction.

Comment: @Sigur, yes but that's the same as you wrote down except I didn't write $x\in A$, can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: @SjoerdSmaal, both could happen from the same hypothesis, so you can not write "if $p$ then $q$. Similarly if $p$ then $r$". You should write "if $p$ then $q$ or $r$. If $q$ then... if $r$ then...". Note that $p$ is the same for both so you write one time, as a global hypothesis.

Comment: @SjoerdSmaal : Hi, to solve the counterpart, it is also possible to use table method in this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435433/proof-of-a-capb-cup-c-a-cap-b-cupa-cap-c . Whenever the two sides of the counterpart match, it is desired to show $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in C$ is a true statement.

Comment: Got it, many thanks

Comment: An alternative proof, where the equivalence is proved directly instead of both directions separately, can be found in this answer to a related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/503464/11994.

Comment: A direct proof can be found in [another answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/503464/11994); I won't duplicate it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the counterpart: assume that $(A\cup B)\cap C = A\cup(B\cap C)$ and let $x\in A$ then $x\in A\cup(B\cap C)$ so $x\in (A\cup B)\cap C$ and therefore $x\in C$ hence we find
$$x\in A\Rightarrow x\in C$$
and you can conclude.

Comment: Can you please explain the second part, where you say $x\in (A\cup B)\cap C$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this, by starting with the most complex side, expanding the definitions, and then simplifying using the laws of logic:

\begin{align}
& (A \cup B) \cap C \;=\; A \cup (B \cap C) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"set extensionality"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in (A \cup B) \cap C \;\equiv\; x \in A \cup (B \cap C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definitions of $\;\cup,\cap\;$, both twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: (x \in A \lor x \in B) \land x \in C \;\equiv\; x \in A \lor (x \in B \land x \in C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: distribute $\;\lor\;$ over $\;\land\;$ in the right hand side of $\;\equiv\;$} \\
& \;\;\;\;\;\phantom"\text{-- alternatively, do this for the left hand side, for the same result"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: (x \in A \lor x \in B) \land x \in C \;\equiv\; (x \in A \lor x \in B) \land (x \in A \lor x \in C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: factor common conjunct from both sides of $\;\equiv\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \lor x \in B \;\Rightarrow\; (x \in C \;\equiv\; x \in A \lor x \in C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic:$\;p \lor q \equiv q\;$ is one of the ways to write $\;p \Rightarrow q\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \lor x \in B \;\Rightarrow\; (x \in A \;\Rightarrow\; x \in C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: combine antecedents"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: (x \in A \lor x \in B) \land x \in A \;\Rightarrow\; x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify antecedent by using $\;x \in A\;$ in the other conjunct"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \;\Rightarrow\; x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& A \subseteq C \\
\end{align}