# Proving a Set Theory identity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Please guys help me prove some Identities.
I need to prove that:
$$B=C \Longleftrightarrow (A \cup B = A \cup C) \land (A \cap B = A \cap C)$$
and also that
$$(A \cap B)\cup C = A\cap(B\cup C) \Longleftrightarrow C\subseteq A $$
i tried everything please help me....

Comment: Since you've tried everything, please post what your ideas are. Will be much easier to help you then.

Comment: Well I tried to say that for all each X that does:
$$x\in (A \cap B)\cup C \rightarrow x\in A\cap(B\cup C)$$ 
and then everything just scrambled and i got nonses...

Comment: If you elaborate your steps we might be able to point out where your calculation went wrong.

Comment: Surely the second statement is obvious & trivial, yes?

Comment: well il write what i did on the second one:
$$\forall x : x\in C \Longleftrightarrow x\in B $$
$$x\in C \land A \Longleftrightarrow x \in B \land A$$
$$x\in C \cap A \Longleftrightarrow x \in B \cap A$$
is it the right way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$(A\cap B)\cup C = A \cap (B\cup C)$ if and only if $C \subset A$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544071/a-cap-b-cup-c-a-cap-b-cup-c-if-and-only-if-c-subset-a), and of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/435483/11994.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster: Note that the OP's second question is not discussed in the post that you point to, therefore we only have a "half-duplicate" here.

Comment: @AlexM. Yes, I missed that. There is a reason why multi-question questions are discouraged.  Especially here, where the questions have no relationship at all (except that they are both about elementary set theory laws).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First statement:

($\Longrightarrow$)
$$(A \cap B)\cup C = A\cap(B\cup C) \Longrightarrow C\subseteq A $$
By contraposition: suppose $C\not\subseteq A$, so there's something $x\in C\setminus A$. Then $x \notin A\cap(B\cup C)$ because $x\notin A$. However, $x\in (A \cap B)\cup C$ because $x\in C$. So $(A \cap B)\cup C \ne A\cap(B\cup C)$.

Or directly:
We have $C\subseteq (A \cap B)\cup C = A\cap(B\cup C) \subseteq A$, because for any $X,Y$, $Y\subseteq X\cup Y$ and $X\cap Y \subseteq X$.

($\Longleftarrow$)
$$(A \cap B)\cup C = A\cap(B\cup C) \Longleftarrow C\subseteq A $$
Suppose $C\subseteq A$. As $\cap$ and $\cup$ distribute over each other, we have:
$$\begin{align}
(A \cap B)\cup C &= (A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C) \\
&= A\cap(B\cup C) \\
\end{align}$$
because $A\cup C = A$.

The second statement is true because... identity.

Comment: update: the $\Longleftarrow$ case (!)

Answer (score 3):

**First Statement**

- $C\subseteq A \Rightarrow (A \cap B)\cup C = A\cap(B\cup C):$

If $C\subseteq A$, then $(A \cup C)=A$ and, it follows from
$$(A \cap B)\cup C = (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C),$$

that $(A \cap B)\cup C = A\cap(B\cup C)$.

- $(A \cap B)\cup C = A\cap(B\cup C) \Rightarrow C\subseteq A:$

Suppose that $C\nsubseteq A$, then there exists $x \in C$ such that $x \not\in A$. But then, it follows that $x \in (A \cap B)\cup C$ while $x \not\in A \cap(B \cup C)$ which implies that $$(A \cap B)\cup C \neq A\cap(B\cup C) $$

---

**Second Statement**

- $B=C \Rightarrow (A \cup B = A \cup C) \land (A \cap B = A \cap C):$

This part is obvious.

- $\underbrace{(A \cup B = A \cup C)}_{(1)} \land \underbrace{(A \cap B = A \cap C)}_{(2)} \Rightarrow B=C:$

Consider $x \in B$. If $x \in A$, then $(2)$ implies that $x \in C$. Otherwise, if $x \not\in A$, then $(1)$ implies that $x \in C$. Hence, $B \subseteq B$. An exactly analogous argument works to prove that if $C \subseteq B$.

Comment: what about the second one?