# $(A\cap B)\cup C = A \cap (B\cup C)$ if and only if $C \subset A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set identity: $(A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C)$ if and only if $C \subset A$.

I started with Venn diagrams and here is the result:
[image]

It is evident that set identity is correct. So I started to prove it algebraic:

1) According to distributive law: $(A \cap B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$

2) ...

I stuck a little. Because $C$ is a `subset` of $A$. I thought of pulling out: $(B \cup C)$ but it seems wrong step to me.

How to prove this identity having in mind that $C \subset A$?

**Updated**

Venn diagram for $C ⊈ A$
[image]

Comment: In addition to the answers: Your Venn diagrams are not entirely correct, for all of $C$ should be green.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s a little easier to go the other way: $A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$, and you’d like to show that this equals $(A\cap B)\cup C$ if and only if $C\subseteq A$.

- Suppose first that $C\subseteq A$; how can you simplify $A\cap C$?
- Now suppose that $C\nsubseteq A$; then there is some $c\in C\setminus A$. Show that this $c$ is an element of $(A\cap B)\cup C$ but not of $(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$, so that these two sets cannot be equal.

Your Venn diagrams show what happens when $C\subseteq A$, so they’re useful in proving one direction of the desired result: if $C\subseteq A$, then the two sets are equal. To see how you might prove the other direction, i.e., that if $C\nsubseteq A$, then the two sets are not equal, you’d do better to look at a Venn diagram showing $C\nsubseteq A$.

Comment: I added diagram for case when C ⊈ A, but this way this identity is incorrect. So I think I should make an assumption that C is a full subset of A. Or I didn't catch the idea :(

Comment: @Dragon: That’s exactly the point: you want to show that when $C\nsubseteq A$, the identity fails. That’s the *only if* half of the proof. What may be throwing you off is that I’ve replaced *identity implies* $C\subseteq A$ with its (logically equivalent) contrapositive, $C\nsubseteq A$ *implies failure of identity*.

Comment: So one can say, if suppose that C ⊈ A this identity fails. Otherwise it is correct. To simplify A∩C... according to commutative law A∩C = C∩A or A \ -C. But this isn't simplification, isn't it?

Comment: @Dragon: $A\cap C$ contains the things that are in both $A$ and $C$. If $C\subseteq A$, every element of $C$ is already in $A$, so $A\cap C=\;$?

Comment: A∩C=A *I feel like being on exam :-[*

Comment: @Dragon: No, $A\cup C=A$; $A\cap C=C$, the smaller of the two sets. (It may feel a bit like an exam, but the more I can get you to work out on your own, the better you’ll understand it.)

Comment: I rethought what was said and here is my proof: 1. Distributive law: (A∩B) U C = (A U C) ∩ (B U C). In case C⊆A: (A U C) ∩ (B U C) = A ∩ (B U C), correspondingly A ∩ (B U C) = A ∩ (B U C). 2. Otherwise according to distributive law: A∩(B∪C)=(A∩B)∪(A∩C). In case C⊆A:  (А∩В) ∪ С = (A∩B)∪C 3. It is proved, that the entity is true if and only if C⊆A.

Comment: @Dragon: You’ve given two different proofs that if $C\subseteq A$, then $(A\cap B)\cup C=A\cap(B\cup C)$. Neither of your arguments proves the opposite implication, that if $(A\cap B)\cup C=A\cap(B\cup C)$, then $C\subseteq A$. What I suggested in my answer was that instead of trying to prove this direction directly, you prove instead the logically equivalent statement that if $C\nsubseteq A$, then $(A\cap B)\cup C\ne A\cap(B\cup C)$.

Comment: Hm, I cannot understand how can one proof identity from opposite implication. And why my proof cannot be full, since in both cases both sides are the same at the end :)

Comment: @Dragon: Let $p$ be the statement that $(A\cap B)\cup C=A\cap(B\cup C)$, and let $q$ be the statement that $C\subseteq A$. You’re supposed to prove that $p\leftrightarrow q$. In both of your arguments you’ve assumed $q$, that $C\subseteq A$, so both of your arguments show that $q\to p$. Neither of them shows that $p\to q$, the other direction of the if and only if ($\leftrightarrow$). My suggestion is that instead of trying to prove $p\to q$ directly, by assuming $p$ and somehow deducing $q$, you try instead to prove $\neg q\to\neg p$; this is logically equivalent and easier to do.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full algebraic proof.  Let's first expand the definitions:

\begin{align}
& (A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"set extensionality"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in (A \cap B) \cup C \;\equiv\; x \in A \cap (B \cup C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$ and $\;\cap\;$, both twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: (x \in A \land x \in B) \lor x \in C \;\equiv\; x \in A \land (x \in B \lor x \in C) \rangle \\
\end{align}

Now we have a choice to make: do we distribute $\;\lor\;$ over $\;\land\;$ in the left hand side, or $\;\land\;$ over $\;\lor\;$ in the right hand side?  Since this expression is completely symmetric, we arbitrarily choose to distribute on the left hand side, and continue our logical simplification after that:

\begin{align}
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"distribute $\;\lor\;$ over $\;\land\;$ on left hand side"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: (x \in A  \lor x \in C) \land (x \in B \lor x \in C) \;\equiv\; x \in A \land (x \in B \lor x \in C) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"extract common conjunct out of $\;\equiv\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B \lor x \in C \;\Rightarrow\; (x \in A  \lor x \in C \equiv x \in A \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify one way of rewriting $\;\Rightarrow\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B \lor x \in C \;\Rightarrow\; (x \in C \Rightarrow x \in A) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"combine both antecedents"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: (x \in B \lor x \in C) \land x \in C \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify antecedent: use $\;x \in C\;$ in other side of $\;\land\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in C \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A \rangle \\
\end{align}

Now we only have to wrap up:

\begin{align}
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& C \subseteq A \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

By Distributivity,

$$ (A \cap B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C ) $$

Suppose $ C \subset A $, then $A \cup C = A $ by definition. Therefore $ (A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C )$

Conversely, suppose $ (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C ) = A \cap (B \cup C )$. We show $C \subset A $. But, by the equality, it is obvious that $ A \cup C = A $. In other words, $C $ must be inside $A$

Comment: Hm... "it is obvious" is always a tricky phrase. E.g. this observation wouldn't work if we'd replace $B\cup C$ by $\varnothing$.