# Proving/Disproving set identity $(A\cap B)\cup C= A\cap (B\cup C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

> For any sets $A$, $B$, $C$; $(A\cap B)\cup C= A\cap (B\cup C)$

[image]

I understand that this means that (A and B) or C = A and (B or C), but how would you prove or disprove these set identities.
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: It is often helpful when proving set equalities to prove $\subset$ and $\supset$ one at a time. This is done by assuming an element is in the (assumed) smaller set, picking apart the information, and trying to reconstruct the pieces that show it is in the (assumed) larger set. To disprove, you usually look for a counterexample. Helpful?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544071/a-cap-b-cup-c-a-cap-b-cup-c-if-and-only-if-c-subset-a

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is normaly using logic expressions:

$$ (A\cap B) \cup C = \{x|\ x\in A,x\in B \lor x\in C \}$$

But in your given example you just have to think about it.

Let's assume $A=\{0\}, B=\{0,1\}, C=\{2\}$ :

$$ (A\cap B)\cup C = \{0,2\} \not = A\cap(B\cup C) = \{0\}$$