# For all set A, B, and C if $(A \cap B) \cup C \subset A \cap (B \cup C)$ then $C \subset A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For all set A, B, and C if $(A \cap B) \cup C \subset A \cap (B \cup C)$ then $C \subset A$?

Is this a theorem or a false proposition? Help!

Comment: Strongly related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/544071/11994

Answer (score 2):

Let $c\in C$ then we have $c\in (A\cap B)\cup C$ hence by the given hypothesis we have $c\in A\cap(B\cup C)$ so $c\in A$. Conclude.

Comment: So could I say. Let A, B,and C be sets such that (A∩B)∪C ⊆A∩(B∪C). Let x∈C. Since x∈ C, then x∈ (A∩B)∪C and because x∈(A∩B)∪C and (A∩B)∪C ⊆A∩(B∪C), then x∈A∩(B∪C). There for x∈A. Thus, C⊆A. Would this be correct?

Comment: Yes correct.${}$

Comment: Sweet!thanks a lot!!!