# Proving that sets aren't equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

X ∪ (Y ∩ Z) = (X ∪ Y) ∩ Z

If it were true I'd know how to prove that it is, but if it's not how do I go about finding a counter example?

Comment: Look for extreme examples. For example if $Z$ is the empty set, then the right-hand side is empty. Can you choose $X,Y$ so the left-hand side is non-empty?

Comment: This is not true.  Most sets are counterexamples.

Comment: Draw two identical Venn-diagrams side-by-side. On the left diagram, shade the subset corresponding to the expression on the left of the identity. Similarly on the right. You can work out a counterexample from there.

Comment: Strongly related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/74449/11994

Answer (score 1):

For $X=\{1\}$, Y=$\{1,2\}$ and $Z=\{2,3\}$ you have that LHS of your expression is $\{1,2\}$ while RHS is $\{2\}$ and the sets are obviously not equal.

Answer (score 1):

$ (X \cup Y) \cap Z = (X \cap Z) \cup (Y \cap Z) $ so I look for a case where $X$ has an element that isn't in $(X \cap Z)$ or $Y$. For exemple $ X =\left \{4  \right \}$, $Y =\left \{1,2  \right \}$ and  $Z =\left \{2,3  \right \}$.

Comment: Not an answer --- use comments or edit your initial post. Post an answer only if it is complete and answers the question.

Comment: Seem's like an answer to me. I gave an answer to the problem plus how I came to that answer. I'd really like some feedback on what's missing to make it an acceptable answer.